# Change jQuery click handler functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using drag and scroll in my page, which is working with the 3 simple handlers mousedown, mousemove and mouseup.

Now i have 2 Issues:

1. all my `.on('click'` and `.click(` events are kind of broken, because since the div is scrolling with the mouse, the cursor stays on the same object and the event fires. How can i change the handler so it only fires when the distance of mousemove between mousedown and mouseup is less than a fixed value? Is it even possible or do i have to create an own one and change all the code? ---SOLVED---
2. I am using `event.preventDefault();` during this drag&scroll to prevent Selection. This results in the user not being able to click on form fields. Is there an easy way to fix this or do i have to stop the selection in another way? ---SOLVED WITH WORKAROUND---

Any ideas would be helpful.

These are the 3 handlers for scrolling:

```
    mouseDownHandler : function(event) {

        if (!$(event.target).closest('.stopscroll').length) {

            event.data.lastCoord = {left: event.clientX, top: event.clientY}; 

            $.event.add( document, "mouseup", dragscroll.mouseUpHandler, event.data );
            $.event.add( document, "mousemove", dragscroll.mouseMoveHandler, event.data );

            $('body').addClass('dragcursor'); //// Add Move Cursor

            if (!$(event.target).closest('.noformelement').length) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }

    },

    mouseMoveHandler : function(event) { 
        var delta = {left: (event.clientX - event.data.lastCoord.left), top: (event.clientY - event.data.lastCoord.top)};

        event.data.scrollable.scrollLeft(event.data.scrollable.scrollLeft() - delta.left);

        $('.th-header').css('margin-left', -event.data.scrollable.scrollLeft()); //// Scrollsync with header

        event.data.scrollable.scrollTop(event.data.scrollable.scrollTop() - delta.top);

        event.data.lastCoord={left: event.clientX, top: event.clientY}

        if (!$(event.target).closest('.noformelement').length) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }

    },

    mouseUpHandler : function(event) {
        $.event.remove( document, "mousemove", dragscroll.mouseMoveHandler);
        $.event.remove( document, "mouseup", dragscroll.mouseUpHandler);

        $('body').removeClass('dragcursor');

        if (!$(event.target).closest('.noformelement').length) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Update/Bump: Just disabling EVERY click event at once would already solve the problem i guess. I tried `$(document).on('click', '*', function() {return false;});` but it does not work...

Comment: show us the code u tried and only then v can help

Comment: added the 3 handlers of drag&scroll.

Comment: well, for problem 2 you can use event.target to check if it's NOT a form element (input/select/textarea) and THEN preventDefault()

Comment: can i check if event.target is a form field or do i have to add a class to every form element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with

```
mouseDownHandler : function(event) {

    if (!$(event.target).closest('.stopscroll').length) {

        event.data.lastCoord = {left: event.clientX, top: event.clientY}; 
        event.data.startCoord = {left: event.clientX, top: event.clientY};
        event.data.allowClick = true;
        $('*').off('click.stop');

        $.event.add( document, "mouseup", dragscroll.mouseUpHandler, event.data );
        $.event.add( document, "mousemove", dragscroll.mouseMoveHandler, event.data );

        if (!$(event.target).closest('.noformelement').length) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }

},

mouseMoveHandler : function(event) { 
    var delta = {left: (event.clientX - event.data.lastCoord.left), top: (event.clientY - event.data.lastCoord.top)};
    var range = {left: (event.clientX - event.data.startCoord.left), top: (event.clientY - event.data.startCoord.top)};
    if (event.data.allowClick && (Math.abs(range.left)>=5 || Math.abs(range.top)>=5)) {
        event.data.allowClick = false;
        $('*').on('click.stop', function() {return false;});
        $('body').addClass('dragcursor'); //// Add Move Cursor
    }

    event.data.scrollable.scrollLeft(event.data.scrollable.scrollLeft() - delta.left);

    $('.th-header').css('margin-left', -event.data.scrollable.scrollLeft()); //// Scrollsync with header

    event.data.scrollable.scrollTop(event.data.scrollable.scrollTop() - delta.top);

    event.data.lastCoord={left: event.clientX, top: event.clientY}

    if (!$(event.target).closest('.noformelement').length) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

}
```